# How to get current inventory from Ansible module?

Tags: ansible

I'm developing custom Ansible module to control Vagrant controlled multiple VM nodes on multiple VM servers following guide https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_modules_general.html. As far as I understand, Ansible iterates over all specified target hosts and executes run_module on them, allowing to module.run_command on each host.

But I need some info from inventory file. For example if VM server is passed to Ansible command then I need to get IPs of VM nodes on that server and I could do it using info from inventory file. How could I get full inventory data from Ansible module Python code?

Comment: You posted the exact same question twice. Can you delete either one please ?

Comment: @Zeitounator, they are not the same. One is about hostname, other is about whole inventory. I though about mixing them in one, but decided that it is bad idea - what if I get good answer about one part of question, but not about other, and other answer about other part, how should I deal with it, which of them should I mark as true answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found answer by myself and posted it as a part of answer to related question https://stackoverflow.com/a/59877713/1927853